# Find the cheapest route between subway stations

Tags: python, python-3.x, routes

Hello i am currently confused with a question and hopefully would like to receive some advice on how to start it.
Below I drew out a map with the destinations and prices

```
                                             6    4 
                                          c  <-b <-a
                                        1 ^        | 1
                                          |        v
                                          g<-f<-e<-d 
                                           1   1   1
```

so based on this map, I am supposed to find the cheapest route from point a to point c but im not sure exactly how to start this question and what I would label my destinations in terms of the price

Comment: you should implement djikstra's algorithm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheapest path algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207987/cheapest-path-algorithm)